# Javafx Popup can't get focus if other application gains focus

Tags: javafx, popup, focus

I use a JavaFX Popup in my application to change the Shipping Address of a customer. That often requires copy pasting the Address from the web browser. If I click on the Popup after the application lost focus it will not regain focus. I first need to click the parent window behind the popup and then click the Popup again to be able to interact with it.
Is there any way to solve that problem, besides using an undecorated stage instead of a Popup?

EDIT:
Here I made a minimal example:

```java
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 600, 600);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Popup popup = new Popup();
        Button btn = new Button("This is a very nice button!");
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> System.out.println("button clicked"));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> System.out.println("textField clicked"));

        VBox popupVBox = new VBox(btn,  textField);
        popupVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
        popupVBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        popup.getContent().add(popupVBox);
        popup.show(scene.getWindow());
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

If you click outside of the application (for example the web browser, to copy some value) then you can not enter Text into the TextField anymore. The button action listener and even the TextField mouse Listener still work and output "button clicked" and "textField clicked" but the blue halo around them does not apppear and you can not enter (or paste) text into the TextField. After you click somewhere on the main Stage of the application it works again.
I tried adding `textField.requestFocus();`
to the mouse Listener of the textfield but that does not do anything.

EDIT 2 after the comment from kleopatra:

I tried adding the following code:

```java
popupVBox.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> {
    popup.getOwnerWindow().requestFocus();
    parentVBox.toFront(); //This is created above and passed to the new Scene instead of diectly passing new VBox() as in the code snippet posted above
});
```

With that code added, popup and its children seem to have focus if the mouse is hoverd over it after an other application had focus, i.e. if clicked with the mouse the blue border appears around the button and textField, and if there is any text in the textField I can move the cursor with the mouse and select the text with the mouse, buy any keyboard inputs are ignored. Actually they are executed in the other application which had focus before. If I ctrl+c in Intellij and try to ctrl+v into the textfield it will be pasted to the Intellij editor. Also the arrow keys move the cursor in the intellij window instead of the textField.
The only way to be able to type anything in the TextField is to click the parent window first.

Also

```
textField.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {
    textField.requestFocus();
});
```

does not do anything

Comment: Create and post a [mre].

Comment: I have added an example JavaFX application to illustrate the problem.

Comment: can reproduce .. wondering whether this is intended behavior: the nodes in the popup can be focused only if the popup's owner window is focused. If the owner is not focused, there is also no way to reach the textfield via keyboard (only by clicking into it). The way out might be to move the owner window toFront on a mouse event, thus allowing a seemless c&p via keyboard.

Comment: I don't think Windows have the function toFront? I tried calling popup.getOwnerWindow().requestFocus(), when the mouse enters the Popup. Afterwards the popup and its children seem to have focus, i.e. if clicked with the mouse the blue border appears around them, and if there is any text in the textField I can move the cursor with the mouse and select the text with the mouse, buy any keyboard inputs are ignored. Actually they are executed in the other application which had focus before. If I ctrl+c in Intellij and try to ctrl+v into the textfield it will be pasted to the Intellij editor.

Comment: `Stage` has `toFront()`, but that doesn't help either. I think this is a bug; the text field has the appearance of having focus but doesn't process keyboard input. (You can paste successfully via a right-click on the mouse, but not via Ctrl-V.)

Comment: @James_D hmm .. that's weird - worksforme in fx11, fx17 and current dev: when I add the stage.toFront to the mouse handler in the example, click into the textfield (the only way to interact with it, so that's needed anyway) the owner window gets the focus along with the textfield, consequently I can c&p via keyboard (ctrl-V)

Comment: Definitely doesn't fix the problem for me. JavaFX/JDK 19, on Mac OS X Monterey.

Comment: @James_D might be OS specific to some extent: toFront in the clicked handler of the textField is working on my win10, toFront in a mouseEntered of the popupContent changes the appearance of the textField to focused without accepting keyboard input

Answer (score 1):

not an answer, just to clarify the comment (will delete if seen by OP :)

```
public class PopupFocus extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(), 300, 300);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setX(10);
        stage.show();

        Popup popup = new Popup();
        Button btn = new Button("This is a very nice button!");
        btn.setOnAction(actionEvent -> System.out.println("button clicked"));

        TextField textField = new TextField();
        textField.setOnMouseClicked(mouseEvent -> {

            System.out.println("textField clicked");
            stage.toFront();

        });

        VBox popupVBox = new VBox(btn,  textField);
        popupVBox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: white");
        popupVBox.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        popup.getContent().add(popupVBox);
        // original
        popup.show(scene.getWindow());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually this seems to solve the problem. When I call ```stage.toFront()``` from ```popupVBox.setOnMouseEntered(mouseEvent -> ...)``` it does not work though. That would prevent having to add a click listener to every single textField (in my case there are multiple).
I don't understand why that would be the case? In both cases it gets called after the mouse re enters the popup.

Comment: verified that it doesn't work in a mouseEntered handler .. hmm .. no idea why not, might well be a bug as @James_D commented: particularly the appearing to be focused (having the focus border) but not accepting keyboard input

Comment: Well I guess I will just add ```((Stage)getOwnerWindow()).toFront();``` to the mouse click event for every text field for now, and hope it won't break in some future JavaFX version. I don't plan to run the programm on mac os for now. Thanks for the help.